# Pick random row from multiple dataframe entries of the same name

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a data frame like this

```
data = [['bob', 1], ['joe', 4], ['joe', 1], ['bob', 3], ['joe', 7]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['name', 'score'])
print(df)
```

looking like

```
  name  score
0  bob      1
1  joe      4
2  joe      1
3  bob      3
4  joe      7
```

I would like to pick a random (not just using the first!) entry for each name and drop the rest.

a result could be e.g.

```
  name  score
2  joe      1
3  bob      3
```

or

```
  name  score
0  bob      1
4  joe      7
```

I guess there is a pythonic way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group by name and then sample one row from each group:

```
df.groupby('name').apply(lambda x: x.sample(1)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

The `reset_index` part is to get rid of the index created by `groupby`.

Comment: Does this takes a random row from the ```dataframe``` for each different ```name```? If yes, this is so cool!

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it does.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the new version of Pandas, >= 1.1.0, that functionality is built-in for [pandas.core.groupby.DataFrame.sample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample.html)

```
df.groupby('name').sample(n=1)
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know about this!